# Is this brute-force algorithm NP-hard?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, time-complexity, np

Here's a brute-force algorithm we're using in a project management system for extracting keywords from abstracts. What is the time complexity of that brute force algorithm? Is it NP-hard, NP-complete, in NP, or in P?

This is the algorithm:

```
public static int search(String pattern, String text) {
  int M = pattern.length();
  int N = text.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < N - M; i++) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      if (text.charAt(i+j) != pattern.charAt(j)) {
         break;
      }
    }
    if (j == M) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: The title grammar is not completely clear, please review...

Comment: In your code, two nested for loops exist. If M is small enough or M varies in limited range, time complexity is Order of N. If M varies greatly, time complexity is Order of (N * M).

Comment: I want to know the in which  category like NP hard( non determinstic polynomial ) , NP complete ( non deterministic , P type ( polynomial)  my problem comes when I  used the bruite force algorithm of pattern matching for analyzing a keyword from the abstract or text document... how I decide in which category the algorithim will come???

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, only *problems* can be in **NP**, or **NP**-hard, or **NP**-complete, or in **P**, so it's not meaningful to ask whether your particular algorithm is **NP**-hard or **NP**-complete.

The particular algorithm you have is the naive string-searching algorithm. Given a text string of length m and a pattern string of length n, it runs in time O((m - n + 1)n). This is a polynomial in the size of the input strings, and so this problem - the string searching problem - belongs to class **P**. It's also in **NP** since every problem in **P** is in **NP**, but it's not known whether that problem is **NP**-hard or **NP**-complete because resolving that question would decide whether **P** = **NP**.

It's reasonable to ask, when you find yourself brute-forcing something, whether your solution is too slow or whether the problem you're trying to solve can be solved more efficiently, and for that it's great to look up the problem and see what's known about it. In you case, there are better algorithms for string searching; the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm runs in worst-case time O(m + n), the Rabin-Karp algorithm on average runs in time O(m + n) and is very easy to implement, and the Boyer-Moore algorithm can run in sublinear time in many cases. However, the fact that your brute-force algorithm isn't as efficient as these algorithms doesn't have anything to do with **NP**-completeness.